# Concurrent, randomizing/shuffling Queue?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am looking for a `java.util.Queue` implementation that can be accessed concurrently and where elements are `added` and/or `removed` randomly. That is, I'm looking for an implementation that **does not** follow the FIFO constraint, but makes sure to shuffle a new entry among the currently contained entries.

<sup><sup>Please notice that [according to the `java.util.Queue` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), "queues typically, but do not necessarily, order elements in a FIFO (first-in-first-out) manner."</sup></sup>

Comment: Sounds like you want a `PriorityBlockingQueue` that inserts elements with a random priority.

Comment: `myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue( Collections.shuffle( new ArrayList( myQueue.add(e) ) ) );`? :)

Comment: Just re-setting `myQueue` at all introduces its own concurrency issues.  But really, writing a `PriorityBlockingQueue` wrapper that uses random priorities shouldn't be terribly complicated.

Comment: random priorities = [using a `Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#PriorityBlockingQueue(int,%20java.util.Comparator)) ? ... good start! I could use my element's `hashCode()` method as an idempotent source of randomness for `myComparator.compare(..)`. ... But generally, with a `Comparator`, I think this "random queue" could run into the problem of having an entry stuck forever on the tail position (... rather than having it *eventually* get to the head position).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can implement your own version based on java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue, like this

```
class ConcurrenRandomizingQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> {
    static Random r = new Random();
    Queue<Entry> q = new PriorityBlockingQueue<Entry>();

    static class Entry implements Comparable<Entry> {
        Object e;
        int p;

        Entry(Object e) {
            this.e = e;
            this.p = r.nextInt();
        }

        public int compareTo(Entry e) {
            return Integer.compare(p, e.p);
        }
    }

    public boolean offer(E e) {
        return q.offer(new Entry(e));
    }

    public E poll() {
        Entry e = q.poll();
        if (e == null)
            return null;
        return (E) e.e;
    }

    public E peek() {
    Entry e = q.peek();
    if (e == null)
        return null;
    return (E) e.e;
    }

    public int size() {
        return q.size();
    }

    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return null; // TODO
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks acceptable! I will try it out! As with my comments to @LouisWasserman 's comments, this solution here may have the problem of an item stuck forever at the queue's tail position: Imagine for a specific `E e`, `r.nextInt()` generating the value `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. This puts `e` to the tail position, only getting to the head position if `e` is the only element in the queue. Now imagine queue-consumer removes 1 element per second and queue-producer adds 2 elements per second. There is realistically no chance `e` will ever move to the head position.